# Google Analytics Funnel for One Page Checkout in Magento

Tags: google-analytics, magento, goal-tracking, bounce-rate

Pushing tracking events to Google Analytics for one page tracking in Magento is tracking 100% for every step after proceeding to billing.

Here is the Funnel Visualizaiton:

[image: Funnel Visualization]

And Here is the Goal Setup:

[image: Goal Setup]

And here is How I push the events to GA:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
 Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function (section, reloadProgressBlock) {
 if (reloadProgressBlock) {
 this.reloadProgressBlock(this.currentStep);
 }

 try {

 ga('send', 'pageview', '/checkout/onepage/' + section + '/');

 } catch (err) {
 }
this.currentStep = section;
 var sectionElement = $('opc-' + section);
 sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
 this.accordion.openSection('opc-' + section);
 if (!reloadProgressBlock) {
 this.resetPreviousSteps();
 }
 };
 //]]>
</script>
```

Does Anyone have any ideas as to why it's showing 100% of people are proceeding through afer step 2. It is not the case as I've tested it personally.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like cart shouldn't be part of the funnel because so many people are entering the checkout process from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

A few things that I suggest you look into:

First of all, the steps in your funnel don't make sense.

**Does every user, no matter what, have to supply a billing address and a shipping address?**

I'm pretty sure Magento's one page checkout allows users to check a box that indicates the shipping address and billing address are the same.

What about users that have purchased before (I'm guessing users can 'create an account')?

Does the site have a 'persistent cart' feature or allow users to 'save' items in anyway (wishlist/bookmark/register)?

Second, why hard code so much of the URL sent as a pageview?

This isn't directly related, but [look at the code suggested here](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-url-fragments-as-pageviews/#update)...I'd let the site report it's own URL, if possible.

It also doesn't seem like you need the 'Regular Expression' setting in your goal configuration...I don't see any problems with it, but it's an extra layer of complexity.

You can use the [Google Tag Assistant extension](https://get.google.com/tagassistant/) to help debug tags...use the **record** feature to check what's being pushed at every step (the recordings persist across page loads).